# Accessing the instance from which an instance is referenced in Python

Tags: python

There probably is a name for what I'm asking for, perhaps it's best shown through an example. Suppose I have these classes:

```
class MonkeyCage(object):
    def __init__(self, dimensions, monkeys=None):
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.monkeys = monkeys

    def add_monkey(self, monkey):
        self.monkeys.append(monkey)


class Monkey(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Suppose I create a zoo, with a MonkeyCage and a first Monkey:

```
>>> dimensions = {'width': 100, 'height': 200, 'depth': 70}
>>> cage = MonkeyCage(dimensions) 
>>> monkey = Monkey("LaundroMat")
```

and add the monkey to the MonkeyCage:

```
>>> cage.add_monkey(monkey)
```

Is there a way -- via the monkey instance -- to get the dimensions of the cage the monkey was added to?

Comment: as you suggested, this kind of entity relationship (one to many) is very common. Normally a foreign key is used to link the monkey to the cage. It is used in RDBMS (Relational DataBase Systems) to link object instances (represented by rows in a table, which in turn represents the object class. You'd have a table for the Monkey and one for the Cage).

Comment: I regularly use ORMs and was indeed wondering whether a similar concept to foreign keys was doable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass the parent somehow on monkey. E.g. in add_monkey, you could set set monkey.parent=self and access it that way.

Comment: Is there any danger in class instances referencing each other (memory-wise or other)?

Comment: @LaundroMat, yes, you create cycles which the reference counting (the default garbage collection strategy) cannot handle. There is an optional garbage collector though that can resolve this. Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html

Answer (score 1):

Just give `monkey` a tag when you add it to that `cage`.

```
class MonkeyCage(object):
    def __init__(self, dimensions, monkeys=None):
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.monkeys = monkeys

    def add_monkey(self, monkey):
        monkey.cage_dimension = self.dimensions
        self.monkeys.append(monkey)


class Monkey(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Then you can get info about `cage` through `monkey.cage_dimensions`